# Is this a knapsack problem?

Tags: optimization

I have a set of $K$ keywords. Each of this keywords can have a set of bids from $1\$,\ldots, N\$$. For each bid for a keyword, it will get a specific amount of clicks and a specific cost. Clicks and Cost are monotonic in bids. Now, the problem is:

---

Select a bid for each of the keyword such that overall clicks across the keywords are maximized such that the cost is still within a given budget $B$. Let $\text{Clicks}(W_i)$ and $\text{Cost}(W_i)$ denote the clicks and cost on the keyword $i$. Then (informally) the problem is to select a value of bid for each keyword such that \begin{align}\max\sum_{i=1}^{K}&\text{Clicks}(W_i) \\s.t.&~~\sum_{i=1}^{K}\text{Cost}(W_i)\leq B\end{align} Is this a type of knapsack problem? Are there any known heuristic in the literature.

---

Following is not important for the question (and thus can be skipped), but is for the curious ones to know how I am solving this currently.

Let $S_{ij}$ denote the cost for using bid $j$ for keyword $i$ and let $C_{ij}$ be the clicks for the same. Let $x_{ij}$ be the indicator variable for using bid $j$ for keyword $i$. Then among variables $x_{i1},\dots,x_{iN}$ only one can be non-zero (i.e. $x_{ij}=1$) whereas the rest is zero (since only one bid can chosen for keyword).

Thus, the whole problem can be formulated mathematically as

\begin{align}\max_{x_{ij}}~&\sum_{i=1}^{K}\sum_{j=1}^{N}x_{ij}C_{ij} \\s.t.~~\sum_{i=1}^{K}\sum_{j=1}^{N}&x_{ij}S_{ij}\leq B\\\sum_{j=1}^{N}x_{ij}=1&~~\forall i\in \{1,\dots,K\}~~,~~x_{ij}\in\{0,1\}\end{align}

Last, two constraints ensure they are indicator variables and only one bid is chosen for a given keyword. Solving this should solve the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called a [multiple-choice knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems#Direct_generalizations). It can be solved in time $O(N B)$ by dynamic programming. The state of the dynamic program is given by a pair $(i, b)$ and the associated value is the maximum value (clicks) you can get with keywords from $1$ to $i$ with a budget at most $b$.

Source: S. Martello, P. Toth. *Knapsack Problems*. Wiley, 1990.